# Issue creating a custom gradle project that outputs a jar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I currently have a custom build.gradle that cmake's and builds a SWIG c++ project and generates a jar file for use in my android project. (The jar is generated within cmake)

My current setup works for the most part.  The jar file is correctly linked to my android project and it builds just fine.  My only problem is that android studio does not recognize the library.  No auto-complete is working and it underlines all uses of my library as an error.

**c++ project build.gradle**

```
task cmakeMyLibrary(type: Exec) {
     inputs.file 'CMakeLists.txt'
     outputs.file 'Makefile'

     ext.jarFile = new File(parent.buildDir, "mylibrary.jar")

     commandLine 'cmake' ...
}

task makeMyLibrary(type: Exec, dependsOn: cmakeMyLibrary) {

    inputs.dir '.'

    outputs.file cmakeMyLibrary.jarFile

    commandLine 'make', '-j10'
}

task cleanMyLibrary(type: Exec) {
     commandLine 'make', 'clean'
}

configurations.create('default')
artifacts {
    it."default"(cmakeMyLibrary.jarFile) {
        builtBy makeMyLibrary
    }
}
```

**android project build.grade**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "18.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile project(':mylibrary')
}
```

Each time I do "Sync project with gradle files" i get an exception:

```
Gradle 'MyApplication6' project refresh failed:
exception during working with external system: java.lang.AssertionError 
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.ModuleDependency.getModuleName(ModuleDependency.java:49) 
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.ModuleDependency. (ModuleDependency.java:43) 
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.Dependency.populate(Dependency.java:143) 
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.dependency.Dependency.extractFrom(Dependency.java:106) 
at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.populateModuleDependencies(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:154) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:232) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$000(GradleProjectResolver.java:60) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:116) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$1.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:112) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:190) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:112) 
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:60) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:53) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:130) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:120) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:441) 
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:504) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171) 
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373) 
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:435) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) 
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:152)
```

When I look at the gradle source it seems to be an assertion that the path passed into getModuleName is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Might not help answer your question, but make sure to upgrade to Build Tools 19.0.1 and the Android Gradle plugin 0.8.1 (or whatever's most recent) from that of 18.1.1 and 0.7.+. There have been a few bugs in the past while working with gradle/IntelliJ that have been caused by older versions of such. You'll want to ensure the Gradle wrapper is up to 0.10 but IntelliJ should prompt you about that.

Might be related: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62391

Perhaps post more about your project structure... or since it's been over a month, let us know if you've found a fix ... :)

Answer (score 0):

if it is pure C++ project and there is no java code in it, may you build it as static or shared lib [including all ABI you want to support ], and have your project import the lib?  Android studio supports this import native lib thing with either gradle-experimental plugin http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental or cmake/ndk-build plugin http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/external-c-builds

Some examples are in this repo https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk, master branch is for gradle-experimental, master-cmake is for cmake plugin. The specific sample similar to your case would be hello-libs [appears in both branches].

Your will have your application project's java code call into its own native[c/c++] code; then from those native code call your SWIG C++ lib. In other words, application project needs a wrapper because it needs to deal with JNI code [I assume], and JNI code have your java class/package's signature in its jni function names.

I am not sure normal JAVA project could directly use a third party lib: the lib function names do not have package and java class name in it.